# Implement the stack that pops the most frequently added item

Tags: c++, data-structures

I was asked to implement a stack that pops the most frequently added item in an interview. I gave him the below answer but he was not happy with the solution.

```
class stack 
{
  // Map of value and count 
  map<int,int> Cntmap; 

  public: 
  void push(int val) 
  { 
    // Find val in map 

    // if found then increment map count 

    // else insert a pair (val,1) 
  } 

  int pop( ) 
  { 
    // Find the Key in Cntmap with max value 

    // using std::max_element 

    // Decrement the Cntmap count for the popped val 
  } 
}
```

Can anyone help me with the correct approach?

Comment: Did you ask him back why he was not happy?

Comment: I did not clear the interview

Answer (score 3):

It's an interesting question, because in `push`, you look up
using the key, and in `pop`, using the mapped value.  `std::map`
supports the first immediately: all you have to do is:

```
++ CntMap[ val ];
```

The `[]` operator will insert an entry if the key isn't
present, initializing the mapped type with its default
constructor, which for an `int` results in `0`.  You don't even
need the `if`.

The second is more difficult.  The comments, however, give the
solution: all you need is a custom `Compare`, which takes two
`std::pair<int, int>`, and compares the second element.
`std::max_element` will return an iterator to the entry you're
interested in, so you can use it directly.  So far so good (and
very simple), but you have to consider error conditions: what
happens if `Cntmap` is empty.  And you might want to remove the
element if the count goes down to `0` (again, simple, since you
have an iterator designating the entry, with both the key and
the value).

Finally, if this is an interview question, I would definitly
point out that the `pop` operation is `O(n)`, and that it might
be worthwhile (although significantly more complicated) to
maintain a secondary index, so that I could find the maximum
element more quickly.  (If I were interviewing, that would be my
next question.  Clearly for advanced programmers, however.)

Comment: `"I gave him the below answer"` implies that the code was the answer OP gave (since there isn't much else in the post), not the code provided by the interviewer. And I find it significantly more likely that an interviewer will ask what's essentially a single sentence than to analyse or complete some provided code.

Comment: @James Kanze  Yes pop() does a linear search. Thank you

Comment: @user1758616 If what Dukeling says is true, then that may be what they didn't like.  (Or it may be just that your answer wasn't precise enough.  They may have expected actual code.)

Comment: @user1758616 Or it may be that you were meant to actually remove the item.  (That's what `pop` usually means.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with only using a single (simple) data structure is that one of the operations will have to be linear (it has to search through all the elements), which is not good enough. In your case, I believe the linear-time operation is `pop`.

**My attempt:**

- Have a linked-list (which will be ordered by frequency).
- Have a map of values to nodes in the linked-list.
- To push, look up the value in the map to get the linked-list node.

  - If found, increment the frequency and move the node appropriately to keep the linked-list sorted.
  - If not found, set the frequency to one and insert into the linked-list in the appropriate place.
- To pop, decrement the frequency of first node of the linked-list and move it appropriately to keep the linked-list sorted, and return the applicable value.

You could have some pretty bad worst-case behaviour if there are many nodes with the same frequency. It should be possible to get constant time add / increment / decrement by having some sort of linked-list of linked-lists, with each node in the large linked-list representing a specific frequency and each linked-list from there representing all nodes having that frequency.

With the above optimization, pop can be O(1) and push can be O(log n). If you use an [`unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) (C++11), push can be O(1).

Another (probably slightly simpler) option is to do something similar to the above, but with a [`heap`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) instead of a linked-list.

Comment: His "stack" is given.  In fact, most of the critical design decisions are given (including the use of `std::max_element`, which means that `pop` will be O(n)).

Comment: @JamesKanze What do you mean "is given"? I see the question as "implement a stack that pops the most frequently added item" and the code is OP's attempt, for which `pop` is O(n) and thus not good enough.

Comment: `To pop, remove the first element from the linked-list and remove the matching item from the map` will break the code, as it removes all copies of the same item instead of only one.

Comment: @Dukeling The first item in the linked-list will be the one most frequently added. You propose the remove it from the list. So, say you push `1` twice and `0` once, then popping leaves you with just `0` and no `1`, even though you pushed two `1` and popped only once. The attempt in the question clearly doesn't to that.

Comment: @Walter Oh, I see I slightly misinterpreted the question. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of a Map, Max-Heap will be better in your case. You can maintain a counter in a similar way. Note that the key of the heap will be the count rather than the actual value itself. When you have to insert a value, search for that value, if found, increment it's key, else, insert the value with key as 1. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: That doesn't solve his problem, since he has to access by the key in `push` (and the comments in `pop` explicitly say to use `std::max_element`, which means linear search).

Comment: I think comments are part of his solution rather than the interview question. Aren't they?

Comment: With a heap, you'll need to search through all the elements to find the correct value in the case of a push, which is too slow.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you'd have to compromise somewhere. But if there's no space constraint, a solution similar to yours can be obtained by using a Map (from values to nodes) and a Max-heap.

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be to wrap [Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) (does the organisation uses boost?).  With this you could create a container which gives ordered access in one direction and hashed in the other. Your implementation of push and pop would use [replace](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/the_tutorial/useful_functions.html#boost_bimap.the_tutorial.useful_functions.replace_and_modify) function of bimap.

Comment: I haven't use Bimap before, but I imagine the frequencies will need to be distinct for this to work, is this correct? If so, I don't see this as conforming to any rational requirements.

Comment: @Dukeling No the frequencies can be `multiset_of<int>`.